# Remote desktop in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, authentication

I have enabled remote desktop on my XP SP3 system.

If my friend takes remote control of my system without my permission my system is connected to him. But a few day before I got the authentication message below, but nowadays I am not receiving this dialog box.

[image]

Please provide help to get this authentication dialog box.

Comment: Did you turn off [fast user switching](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279765)?

Comment: Have you recently changed the access that user has? When an administrator connects, they don't have to request permission, but standard users do have to.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible he uses another account than the one you are currently using, this wouldn't cause you to log off and therefore would not warn you you are about to be logged off if accepted. I'm not 100% sure but this could be the issue. Ask your friend to connect to your PC and then go to Task manager. There should be a "Users" tab showing all logged on users.